R-Markdown chunk is too slow when knitted to PDF
THIS IS THE CODE OF THE CHUNK:
{r knn, include=FALSE}

library(class)  # Load the class library for KNN

# Define the number of neighbors
k <- 5  # You can adjust this value based on your preference or cross-validation results

# Train the KNN model
knn_model <- knn(train = x_train_final, test = x_test_final, cl = y_train, k = k)

# Make predictions using the test set
knn_predictions <- as.factor(knn_model)

# Check the performance with respect to y_test
knn_accuracy <- mean(knn_predictions == y_test)
print(paste("Accuracy of KNN model:", knn_accuracy))

# You can also calculate other performance metrics like confusion matrix, precision,   recall, F1-score, etc. based on your requirement

# To calculate AUC for KNN, you can use the pROC package
library(pROC)
knn_auc <- auc(roc(as.numeric(y_test) - 1, as.numeric(knn_predictions) - 1))
print(paste("AUC of KNN model:", knn_auc))

When I knit the rmarkdown file to PDF, it takes too much time to process this chunk (while knitting, it stays fixed at 80% on "knn" chunk). Finally, I can't even manage to knit the whole document to PDF since a series of errors occur.
I could manage to knit the file before adding chunk with ml models.
May someone help me?
Before adding chunks with ml models (such as KNN, CART, RF, XGboost, etc..), I could easily manage to knit my rmarkdown to PDF. However, once I've added such chunks, I faced anomalies and errors. More specifically:
It takes a lot of time (when knitting) to process some chunks such as "knn" and "random_forest" ones. It now takes almost 30 mins to process all chunks. Moreover, after 30 mins (on average), the execution stops and this error appears:
A new version of TeX Live has been released. If you need to install or update any LaTeX packages, you have to upgrade TinyTeX with tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(repository = "illinois").
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \mathop 
l.664   \(X_\min
                \) is the minimum value of the feature across the dataset 

Errore: LaTeX failed to compile thesis.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See thesis.log for more info.
Esecuzione interrotta


How long does it take to run that code outside of r markdown?

you can add r chunk option cache=TRUE to cache results so they load faster for future testing.resource link the error is referencing your thesis.tex file that I don't see in your question.
